# JPA - unique bi-directional entity relationship

Tags: sql, database, jpa, unique, relation

I want to make relations between my "Tag" entity. The relationships are bi-directional and are stored in my entity "TagRelation":

[image]

Each tag relation should only have 1 entry in the tag_relations table, since the direction of the relation has no meaning. For example if I insert:

"Forest" (tag 1) <-> "Tree" (tag 2)

I should not be possible to insert the relationship the other way around:

"Tree" (tag 1) <-> "Forest" (tag 2)

This is the SQL code of the table tag_relation:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag_relation` (
    id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `tag_id_1` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `tag_id_2` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `type` ENUM('related_subject','synonymous','alternative_writing') NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
    INDEX `fk_tag_1` (`tag_id_1` ASC) ,
    INDEX `fk_tag_2` (`tag_id_2` ASC) ,
    UNIQUE INDEX `ux_relation_1_2` (`tag_id_1` ASC, `tag_id_2` ASC) ,
    UNIQUE INDEX `ux_relation_2_1` (`tag_id_2` ASC, `tag_id_1` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_tag_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id_1` )
        REFERENCES `mm`.`tag` (`id` )
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_tag_2`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id_2` )
        REFERENCES `mm`.`tag` (`id` )
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

The unique indexes as they are now do not enforce the unique relationship that I want. How can I enforce this in my database?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so there might be a better solution. But if you consider that [tag1, tag2] is equals to [tag2, tag1], you could enforce the rule that the couple is always inserted with the lowest ID in the first column, and the biggest ID in the second one. This can be enfoced by a simple checked constraint.

Comment: You mean with a trigger? The solution sounds good. I have to find out how to write that trigger.

Comment: I don't think it works because the TagRelation entity already had set the tag_1 and tag_2 references. The trigger you suggested could turn those around when inserted in the db, leading to an inconsistency between the TagRelation entity and the database. But maybe I could make a trigger that checks if there is a unique relation already in the database.

Comment: I'm not talking about a trigger. I'm talking about a check constraint. The job of ordering them correctly would be the job of the JPA entity.

Comment: I see. How do I make such a constraint?

Comment: The solution I'm using now is, before I insert the TagRelation, I set the Tag with the lowest id as tag 1. With the currents constrains (see post above) the TagRelation will always have two unique tags. This enforcement is done at application + database level. I would also have a enforcement just at database level.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using MySQL. Unfortunately, it doesn't support check constraint. See http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints, or use a real database like PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you want to post you answer as a solution, I can submit it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are the relation types dynamic at runtime? if not I think you would be better placing the relationships directly in the tag:

```
public class Tag{
    @OneToOne private Tag related_subject;
    @OneToOne private Tag synonymous;
    @OneToOne private Tag alternative_writing;
    //setters and getters
}
```

This will make your relations more secure and even more performant.

Comment: I actually implemented the solution of JB Nizet, which works fine. I'm not sure if I understand your solution. It must be possible to have multiple relations of the same type, but I guess the Tag relations in your solution could be changed to List<Tag>. But in that case, JPA will create 3 connections tables. Then, it would be easier to just create one tag_relation myself.